# Jquery to remove class from body tag

Tags: jquery, css

My page is dynamically generating the body class, and it's some WordPress plugin generating.  I wanted to easily remove that class, so figured I could strip with jQuery.  I thought this would remove the class "page" from the body code which ends up looking like:

```
<body class="page otherattr otherattr2 etc etc">
```

By using this jquery in my footer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("body").removeClass("page");
    });
</script>
```

But it doesn't seem to work, am I missing something?

Comment: That should work. Are you getting any errors in the console? Have you included jQuery?

Comment: When you say *dynamically generating the body class*, does this mean WordPress generates it on the server and you want to remove it with Javascript? Or does that mean something else? Also, have you considered overriding it (`body.page { canceling properties }`)?

Comment: That code looks fine to me. Can you verify that the script is being run and that the body tag has that class at the time you're trying to remove it (meaning it isn't being added dynamically as some point after you've remove code runs)?

Comment: I think by dynamically he means that the plugin is run *after* the page loads. I've seen a few wordpress plugins that use some jQuery to do generate additional content. I'm guessing he wants this to be called as soon as the body tag is ready but also as soon as the class is added...easiest thing is probably to dig into the plugin and remove the code that does this or monkeypatch it with a wrapper that does the removeClass part ;-)

Comment: Why not use `$(document.body)` rather than `$("body")`.  Both will work, but giving it the element directly rather than in text should be better (15% faster in [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/body-as-text-vs-document-body)).

Answer (score 7):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(window).load(function () {
    $("body").removeClass("page");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If with *dynamically* you mean in the back-end (*server side*) then your code should work..

If you mean with some other javascript then you should make sure that your code is run after the code that adds it..

On way would be to add a delay, or even better to keep checking until it is added..

Something like

```
$(function cleanBody(){
  var body = $('body');

  if ( body.is('.page') ){
     body.removeClass('page');
  } else {
    setTimeout(cleanBody, 500);
  }
});
```

should do it..

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your script at the bottom of the page and check whether it is working fine. If it is the case then the class "page" is getting appended from another javascript code. Try finding it and place your removal code after that.